# How to extract close-by locations from a matrix?

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, data-analysis

I got a matrix containing distances in kilometers in R:

```
structure(c(0, 0.299178017189202, 0.472092562775104, 31.0627244156583, 
68.5367247200762, 138.470931004348, 0.299178017189202, 0, 0.298855070662631, 
31.1130225293117, 68.70216465045, 138.511349341572, 0.472092562775104, 
0.298855070662631, 0, 31.41104035093, 68.9840966568129, 138.808325566886, 
31.0627244156583, 31.1130225293117, 31.41104035093, 0, 42.1218726943979, 
107.425908015876, 68.5367247200762, 68.70216465045, 68.9840966568129, 
42.1218726943979, 0, 82.3261005757895, 138.470931004348, 138.511349341572, 
138.808325566886, 107.425908015876, 82.3261005757895, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("260100023-01", "260100023-05", "260100034-01", 
"260100034-02", "260100238-00", "260201036-00"), c("260100023-01", 
"260100023-05", "260100034-01", "260100034-02", "260100238-00", 
"260201036-00")))
```

The ID's are representing different locations. Now, I want to create a list, that shows for every ID, which other ID's are within a radius of 40 kilometers. I suppose the key to do this, is an "if"-function. But I don't know how to apply it line by line on every cell of a matrix.

Comment: Please share your matrix using `dput`?

Comment: For a matrix called `ma` one way to start would be `which(ma < 40, arr.ind = TRUE)`.

Comment: @Quinten I added the matrix to the question. It's my first time using put, I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the elements from a single column, where the distance is at most 40 as follows:

```
col <- data[1, ]
col[col < 40]
## 260100023-01 260100023-05 260100034-01 260100034-02 
##   0.0000000    0.2991780    0.4720926   31.0627244
```

As you can see, the resulting vector has names which are exactly the IDs of the locations that are within 40 kilometers. Using `names()`, we can extract
the IDs:

```
names(col[col < 40])
## [1] "260100023-01" "260100023-05" "260100034-01" "260100034-02"
```

Now that we know how to do this for a single column, we can use `apply()` to run this function for all columns

```
apply(data, 2, function(col) names(col[col > 40]))
## $`260100023-01`
## [1] "260100238-00" "260201036-00"
## 
## $`260100023-05`
## [1] "260100238-00" "260201036-00"
## 
## $`260100034-01`
## [1] "260100238-00" "260201036-00"
## 
## $`260100034-02`
## [1] "260100238-00" "260201036-00"
## 
## $`260100238-00`
## [1] "260100023-01" "260100023-05" "260100034-01" "260100034-02" "260201036-00"
## 
## $`260201036-00`
## [1] "260100023-01" "260100023-05" "260100034-01" "260100034-02" "260100238-00"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sometimes I do not see the right way of thinking

Comment: That's quite normal and you will get used to the right way of thinking with time. If the answer helped, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: You shouldn't teach how to mask the `col()` function though, not best practice.

Comment: @jay.sf Do you have a better practice?

Comment: @Sam Yeah, (in a fresh R session) just type the name you want to use once, if something appears, the name is already used. Use something different then - easy to keep in mind actually.